# My Lyx install has started producing \boldsymbol{} instead of \mathbf{} when pressing CTRL+B - how to fix?

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I recently updated my Lyx installation on Windows, and have noticed that when I press CTRL+B in math mode, it is now producing `\boldysymbol{}` instead of `\mathbf{}`. I would like to get it back to producing `\mathbf{}`. What may have caused this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What caused the change for you, I do not know. The default bindings are Ctrl+B for `font-boldsymbol` and Ctrl+Alt+B for `font-bold`, and you can exchange them in the preferences.

Comment: Yup, they were reversed.  Not sure how that happened.  Thanks!